# ember controller for rendered template

Tags: ember.js

I have a collection of foos, and each foo has its own collection of bars.  I want to be able to display a selected foo using routes, but then the foo's bars are listed as part of the display.

All that is straight forward except that each bar may contain an attribute that means I want to apply different styles to it.  So, I am using a *render* handlebars helper inside an *each* , like so -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="foo">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <div>
        <table>
            {{#each bar in bars}}
                {{render bar bar}}
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

and the bar template looks like this -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bar">
    <tr><td>
        <div {{bind-attr class="bar.bold:bold"}}>{{bar.name}}</div>
    </td></tr>
</script>
```

The thing is that I can't figure out how to define the controller.  The above just works if the model contains bars with a bold property but what if that's not the case and I need to calculate the property?

I tried variations on this -

```
App.BarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
isBold: function(){
    return this.get('bold');
}.property('isBold'),});
```

(modifying the bind-attr helper accordingly), and I put a breakpoint on the return.  It is never hit.

I have a jsfiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/martinp999/ZbjH9/7/).  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hold *state* on a per item basis using an `itemController` is the right approach.

But to get your `BarController` being picked up and used and therefore your computed property getting invoked you have to set the `itemController` property on your `{{each}}` helper to do so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="foo">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  <div>
    <table>
        {{#each bar in bars itemController="bar"}}
            {{render bar bar}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
  </div>
</script>
```

See here your [modified and working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tC3cy/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's the sort of thing I was thinking of.  Had no idea that I'd have to declare it on the each helper though.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing which triggers your event in the controller like a observer or an action.

Comment: Sorry, new to ember.  What event are you talking about?  I want to display the bars with different styles depending on a property in the data.  There isn't an event?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erhard/ZbjH9/8/    It is solved with an if .  No controller action needed. Is this what You want ?

Comment: Well, that sort of does what I want.  It moves the logic from the controller to the handlebars helpers.  But, I actually want to use one class if true else another class.  You're supposed to be able to do this with a combination of `{{bind-attr class="view.someBool:class-name-if-true:class-name-if-false"}}` and a custom property in the controller that returns a boolean.

Comment: I think You have to create a view-helper of your own - described there http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/

Comment: Not sure that I understand views yet.  Next thing on my list... I think. ;-)